# Elasticsearch applying a mapping by default

Tags: elasticsearch

I want my string fields in elasticsearch not be analyzed by default and be applied it to all index in elasticsearch without any index level configuration. Currently I have to go and setup the mapping for each index, indexType individually like this,

```
POST sellers/sellerDailyRecord/_mapping
{
"sellerDailyRecord" : {
    "dynamic_templates" : [
        {
            "template1" : {
                "match" : "*",
                "match_mapping_type" : "string",
                "mapping" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Can I make the above configuration default mapping for all indexType? I read elasticsearch docs for root object but I am not able to figure out how to do this. Can anyone help me figure out this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a better way of doing this using index templates. This solved my problem and I don't have to go do this for each and every index:

```
PUT _template/not_analyzed_template
{
    "template": "*", 
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "template_1": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "match": "*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this while creating index, so that it applies to all the types created inside the index,

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/t1" -d'
{
   "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
         "dynamic_templates": [
            {
               "string_template": {
                  "match": "*",
                  "match_mapping_type": "string",
                  "mapping": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index" :"not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks this would work. Is there any way in which I don't have to do this for each and every index?